# The sum of the solutions of $2e^{2x}-5e^{x}+4=0$ is $\ln k$. Find $k$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The sum of the solutions of the equation 
>   $2e^{2x}-5e^{x}+4=0$  is $\ln k$, then find the value of $k$.

Answer (score 1):

$$2=e^{x_1}e^{x_2}=e^{x_1+x_2}=e^{\ln{k}}.$$
Can you end it now?

Answer (score 0):

If $u$ and $v$ are the solutions, then $e^{u+v}=e^ue^v=4/2=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let there are functions

$$\varphi(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\ \mathrm{and}\  \psi(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\left(f^{-1}(f(x))\right)^n.$$

But $x = f^{-1}(f(x))$, thereby $$\varphi(x) = \psi(x) = \phi(f(x)) .$$

Therefore $$\varphi(x_i) = 0 \longleftrightarrow \phi(f(x_i)) = 0.$$

Let $a_k = 0$ for $k \ge 3$, and $a_2,a_1,a_0 = 2,-5,4$, and $f(x) = \ln x$, it is $$\varphi(x) = 2x^2 - 5x + 4 = 2e^{2\ln x} - 5e^{\ln x} + 4.$$

Thereby the roots of $\varphi(x) = 0$ are $$x_\pm = \frac{5 \pm i\sqrt{7}}{4}$$ as will as $\ln x_\pm$ are roots of the $\phi(\ln x) = 0$.

Comment: Yes, there will be no roots but there will be two solutions for the question.
And thanks for answering
:D